# What is the difference between access tokens and auth_codes in OAuth 2

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using the [OAuth 2.0 PHP Library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/) to develop a OAuth 2.0 server in PHP.

In the example of that library I can see 3 tables: `auth_codes`, `clients` and `tokens`.

As far as I know tokens are used to access the data and auth codes are used to obtain tokens.

But the problem is that if i do

```
...authorize.php?client_id=0123456789ab&response_type=token&state=test_state
```

I can get token without even getting the access code.

How is that possible ? Is this a proper implementation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the 2 workflows? When to use Authorization Code flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321455/what-is-the-difference-between-the-2-workflows-when-to-use-authorization-code-f)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two flows for [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) authentcation.

1. Two-legged OAuth
2. Three-legged OAuth

Here you have encountered *2-legged OAuth* which doesn't require the auth_code to get access_token dance :)

These are some useful links that will help you understand the difference better.

1. http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2011/01/10/2-legged-vs-3-legged-oauth/
2. https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/2leggedoauth/2opensocialrestapi