# Google Plus Authentication within an Android App

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, backend, google-oauth

I'm trying Google Plus sign-in in an Android app (with backend support).

I could get access token and email from the user, but know I don't know how should I recognise this user from the server. I'm sending this to the server (email and oauth token) with a POST throught SSL

Of course I could recognise them with their email, but that would open the doors for everyone how knows another email that's on the database.

How could I verify that the user's correctly authenticated and has sent me the correct oauth token for this email?

Thanks!

Comment: user clicks on sign in from G+, authenticates and your app gets the token. you can fetch data using this token? where do you need to use the email ID? are you maintaining user accounts locally or something?

Comment: Javier Manzano, could you please post the code you used to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1) Generally, you shouldn't be sending the auth token over the wire if you can help it. Instead you should be using a hybrid flow where the client gets a one time code when it authenticates, passes you this one time code, and you can redeem this for an auth token and a refresh token. Using this method, your server also has offline access on behalf of the user. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow for details. **However**, I'm not entirely sure how this works with the Android library.

2) Regardless of (1), generally what you can do is to use the plus.people.get method on the server with the userID of "me" to get the user's userID and verify this against what you're expecting. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a perfect case to use the Authorization code flow.

See this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tivoli.fim.doc_6.2.2%2Fconfig%2Fconcept%2FOAuth20Workflow.html). It has some workflow diagrams that you might want to see. In your case the user should authenticate and receive an authorization code (and not a token!).

He would then send the authorization code to your server, you can exchange this code for access + refresh tokens. Have your client registered for the scope and have the client credentials.

The access token flow (called the implicit grant flow) is generally used when requests need to be sent directly from the user's browser.

And, as @Prisoner already mentioned, you will have offline access too. That would be a much better design.

EDIT - you might also want to take a look at [What is the difference between the 2 workflows? When to use Authorization Code flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321455/oauth-2-0-difference-between-2-workflows-when-to-use-authorization-code-flow)