# Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing on POST for requesting access token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth-2.0, nsurlconnection

I am struggling to get the access token on Quizlet (oauth2). Everything works fine so far, I can make the user accepting my app on Quizlet, get redirected, but when requesting the access token via NSURLConnection, I always get the following error:

> 2013-08-17 09:39:33.422 Abiliator[49549:c07] Returned data in string format: {"http_code":400,"error":"invalid_request","error_title":"Not Allowed","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

Here the code for the user authentication (must be via browser according to spec):

```
- (void) authenticateQuizletUser
{

NSString *quizletRandomString = [abiliatorAppDelegate GetUUID];
NSString *authURLString = [@"https://quizlet.com/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=" stringByAppendingString:@"<myID>&scope=read"];
authURLString = [authURLString stringByAppendingString:@"&state="];
authURLString = [authURLString stringByAppendingString:quizletRandomString];
authURLString = [authURLString stringByAppendingString:@"&redirect_uri=Abiliator://after_oauth"];

NSLog(@"Authentication URL sent: %@", authURLString);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: authURLString]];

}
```

That works fine, as I mentioned. The app starts Safari and the user must acknowledge the request entering user id and password and the server redirects into my app, which I catch in the method below, which then throws the error described.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
if (!url) {  return NO; }
NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"Received URL: %@", URLString);
NSString *myURLQuery = [url query];
NSString *myAuthCode = [self getAuthorizationCodeFromURL:myURLQuery];
NSLog(@"Component1: %@", myAuthCode);
NSString *authPasswd = @"myPasswd";
NSString *username=@"myUserName";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token"]];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"Abiliator://after_oauth" forHTTPHeaderField:@"redirect_uri"];

// According to Quizlet API doc: You must set this (grant_type) to the string "authorization_code". 
[request setValue:@"authorization_code" forHTTPHeaderField:@"grant_type"];
[request setValue:myAuthCode forHTTPHeaderField:@"code"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, authPasswd];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


return YES; }
```

Any help hihgly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth2 [defines 4 ways](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4) to gain an access token. The most secure and most complicated is the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) that is used by Quizlet as described [here](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization_code_flow/).

The Authorization Code Grant consists of two steps:

- get an authorization code (the user authenticates here outside of your app before the flow passes back to you via redirect)
- change the authorization code into an access token

You did the first call right. The problem with the second call is that you put the `grant_type` parameter in the wrong place of your request.
In this line you treat it as an HTTP header:

```
[request setValue:@"authorization_code" forHTTPHeaderField:@"grant_type"];
```

And here you also treat the authorization code as an HTTP header:

```
[request setValue:myAuthCode forHTTPHeaderField:@"code"];
```

But OAuth2 requires you to put both into the body of your request. Here is an example of a correct request:

```
POST /oauth/token/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 999
Authorization: Basic xxx

grant_type=authorization_code&code=theCodeYouGotInTheFirstStep&
scope=somescope&redirect_uri=theSameUriYouIncludedEarlier
```

(The stuff below the empty line is your request's body)
(I added the linebreak in the body only for readability - you must not include it in a request)

Bonus answer: Please keep in mind that OAuth2 is insecure by default: If you don't do a bit of extra work, your app is vulnerable to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) attacks as even [mentioned in the OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12). To prevent this OAuth2 offers you the `state` parameter. You have to generate a non-guessable value for your `state` and include it in the first request. You must not fire the second request, if the `state` returned by the server is not the same you generated earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As for the security, I do pass the state parameter, see the first code in my question. I just did not implement the validation check yet. As for body, I also tried this, same result. I updated my post with the body snippet as I have implemented.

Comment: @renesteg nobody else can see your snipped because the edit was rejected, but there you, too, left out the grant_type but instead inserted things that belong into the header like content-type and basic authorization. Please try it again with the string i placed in my answer.

Comment: strange that edits are being rejected, anyway, here the snipped I use for the body method:     [bodyData appendData:[postMethodString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[authCodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[contentTypeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[basicAuthorizationString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
and then I use     [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
should be ok right?

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful to see the rest of your implementation. How are you obtaining the `code`? Also, what credentials (`authPasswd` & `username`) are you using? These should be your app's (as opposed to the end user's). You get these in Quizlet's Dev Dashboard.

> Note: this OAuth flow is not recommended for devices, as it requires secrets to be stored in the device. Using the `implicit` flow is, but I'm not sure Quizlet supports it.

Comment: Thanks Eugenio for your feedback. I am using the credentials for my app as Quizlet specifies: I edited my post to show the first step of the oauth 2 process. No issue at all. Only thing I don't do yet is comparing the sent random string for the state. But this should not be an issue at all, as this is additional security on the app side only. As for your note: what do you mean, by implicit flow?

Comment: All looks good on the surface...can you put a network trace to see what is actually being sent when you request the token? "implicit" is just another flow in which you can request the token directly (no code exchange). See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321455/oauth-2-0-difference-between-2-workflows-when-to-use-authorization-code-flow/16341985#16341985

Comment: This is 3-legged flow. Implicit grant is used when the client is trusted. Implicit cuts the flow of send the auth code back to client, other wise, a client has to present its credentials & parameters along with auth code to generate access token and one primary reason is to validate whether the Auth code is being presented buy same client for which it was generated, (redirect_uri is mandatory here).

Comment: if you *must* store credentials on the device, be sure to use the keychain API

Comment: @nielsbot The whole point of OAuth2's Authorization Code Grant is that the user's credentials are not stored on you device and not even ever handed to the client app.

Comment: Just responding to the quote above

Answer (score 0):

Send your oauth parameters as payload. You should not be sending them as headers. For Example your request should looks like

```
POST /token 

Headers:

Authorization: Basic R0cxSWJdHpINDVhang5Y0VlSUxxalBSOW5SU0NBWA==

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Payload:

grant_type=authorization_code&code=Wirr951e&scope=READ&redirect_uri=www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with similar issue, here is what worked for me.

Need to define Header right (if I explain it Karate script way),

````
 * def keycloak_extension = "keycloak authorization to generate the access token put here"

 * configure headers = {'Content-Type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",'Authorization':#("Basic " +keycloakAuthSecret)}
    
 Given path keycloak_extension
 And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
 And request '{}'
 When method post
 And status 200
 * def accessToken = response.access_token ```


How to encode using Base64 can use this link:
https://www.base64decode.org/ 

Can also refer to this video, to understand it better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-Q-Kywk1O4
````