# What is Authorization grant in Auth 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I got how the authorization grants work flow is but i am not getting what actually are these ? Like What is Implicit Authentication grant type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth2 has many authorization flows. You can check the spec for full details: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4

The 2 most frequently found ones are `authorization code` & `implicit`. See this other SO question on the main differences:  [What is the difference between the OAuth Authorization Code and Implicit workflows? When to use each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321455/what-is-the-difference-between-the-2-workflows-when-to-use-authorization-code-f/16341985#16341985)

Here's [another article](https://docs.auth0.com/protocols) that explains them. Although these are explained in the context of our service ([Auth0](https://auth0.com)), the principles are independent and true for any implementation.